# Why "accepts_nested_attributes_for" is not working?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I have following models

Order

```
    class Order < ApplicationRecord
         has_many  :items
         accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
    end
```

and Item

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord


belongs_to  :order

end
```

And I have following Json to parse where an order contains multiple items

```
    {
  "location": "takeAway",
  "status": "preparing",
  "items": [
    {
        "id":2,
      "name": "coffee",
      "quantity": 1,
      "milk": "whole",
      "size": "small"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have following code my controller.

```
 params.require(:order).permit(:location, :status, items_attributes:  [:id, :name, :quantity, :milk, :size])
```

Why I am not able to save Order records with item records? Can someone please help?

Comment: I don't think you should be sending id in item_attributes, and what is the error you are getting ? Can you please share.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: I dont see records created in Items table

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is that you are receiving key `items` in params, but you permitted `items_attributes`. You, should make sure that you receive `items_attributes` in params instead of `items`. Only then, it will auto assign attributes to `items` records.

So, your final params hash must look like this:

```
    {
      "location": "takeAway",
      "status": "preparing",
      "items_attributes": [
        {
          "id":2,
          "name": "coffee",
          "quantity": 1,
          "milk": "whole",
          "size": "small"
        }
      ]
    }
```

If you want to keep `items` key in params, then you will have to build `Item` objects yourself in controller.

Comment: I don't see items record created. Can you please help?

Comment: Please mention which parts of my suggestions you tried?

Comment: Try adding `attr_accessible :items_attributes` to your `Order` model.